# jquery. Click on div, take id of the div and use the id as part of jquery .css("background-image"

Tags: jquery

Here is example http://jsfiddle.net/apye01n0/6/

At first html

```
<div id="large_photo" style="width:100px; height:100px;" > To show one large photo </div>

<div id="base_64_string0" class="thbn_photo" style="float:left; 
background-color: #b0c4de; height: 50px; width: 50px; margin: 0 3px 3px 0; "></div>
```

Want on click on `class="thbn_photo"`, get value of `id` and use the value in below jquery code. I have defined jquery variable and variable name is value of the clicked id.

Here is jquery variable

```
base_64_string0 = 'R0lGODlhRgAzAJE..';
```

Here is remaining jquery code

```
$(document).on('click', '.thbn_photo', function(){
alert( this.id );

//$("#large_photo").css("background-image", "url('data:image;base64," + base_64_string0 + "')");//This works
$("#large_photo").css("background-image", "url('data:image;base64," + this.id + "')");//This does not work

});
```

On click with `alert( this.id );` i see `base_64_string0`.

So i expect if i insert `this.id` in `url('data:image;base64," + this.id + "')` i would get the same as `url('data:image;base64," + base_64_string0 + "'`.

With `url('data:image;base64," + base_64_string0 + "')` all works (i manually wrote variable name (`base_64_string0`)).

But with `url('data:image;base64," + this.id + "')` does not work. In generated source see like `background-image: url(&quot;data:image;base64,base_64_string1&quot;);">`. How to get this code to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use a parameter value as the variable name.
Instead you can map that parameter to some value.
I have used an array of images with the parameter value as a key to the image code.
See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/apye01n0/10/)

```
var images = [];
images['base_64_string0'] = 'R0lGODlhRgAz';
```

Answer (score 2):

You want use id parameter like a name of variable. This is mistake.

```
img = {
    base_64_string0 : 'R0lGODlhRgAzAJE..'
}
```

and

```
"url('data:image;base64," + img[this.id] + "')"
```

http://jsfiddle.net/apye01n0/15/

Comment: What if i have `base_64_string1, `base_64_string2` and so on? I tried to add inside `img={}`, but does not work. http://jsfiddle.net/apye01n0/18/

Comment: The correct syntax javascript for object: `img = { base1 : '....', base2 : '....'  }` You must use comma instead of semicolon

Answer (score 0):

Hey brother first Pass `this.id` to one variable and pass the value of that variable instead of `this.id`
like given below :

```
$(document).on('click', '.thbn_photo', function(){
alert( this.id );
 var str=this.id; //Here is declaration of variable
//$("#large_photo").css("background-image", "url('data:image;base64," + base_64_string0 + "')");//This works
$("#large_photo").css("background-image", "url('data:image;base64," + str + "')");

});
```